# Arcsine law for gaussian random walk

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks

Consider the random walk $S_i=Z_1+\dots+Z_i$, where the $Z_i$'s are iid $N(0,1)$ and $i\in\{1\dots n\}$. Is there an arcsine law, similar to the one for the $\{\pm 1\}$ case?

Comment: Yes, there is an arcsine law. See "On the number of positive sums of independent variables" by Erd$\ddot{\text{o}}$s and Kac. A further generalization is given by Erik Sparre Andersen's "On the number of positive sums of random variables": If the i.i.d. steps have a symmetric density function (about $x=0$), then there is an arcsine law.

Comment: Thank you very much!